# Getting help from types in Python

Tags: python, visual-studio-code

Coming from Typescript to Python, and being a bit confused. There seems to be Typings for many functions, however, if I do:

```py
import tensorflow_datasets as tfds

(ds_train, ds_test), ds_info = tfds.load('cifar10', split=['train', 'test'], with_info=True, as_supervised=True)
```

I get `Any` for any of the variables on the right.

I am aware they provide some typings, but it is very difficult to code without having types for each of the outputs (ds_train, etc)

I have consider the `typings` package but this won't change the `Any`s if I add it.

How do we get Type information on Python3 for such cases ?

---

For example, this wouldn't add anything:

```py
ds_train: tf.data.Dataset
```

---

Currently I added the types this way:

```py
ds_train: tf.data.Dataset[Tuple[tf.Tensor, int]]
ds_test: tf.data.Dataset[Tuple[tf.Tensor, int]]
ds_info: tfds.core.DatasetInfo
```

Comment: so, looking at the [source code](https://github.com/tensorflow/datasets/blob/35f93c4e901557babb1c0088f9f56bc8a9f53fda/tensorflow_datasets/core/load.py#L503) for that function, there seems to be no return type annotation, so it will implicitly be `typing.Any`.

Comment: What do you mean by  "`ds_train: tf.data.Dataset` won't add anything"?

Comment: What do you mean "I get Any for any of the variables on the right"?  **Get** from where?

Comment: what is the problem, you can assign `Any` to any variable, welcome to Python. In Python you are expected to know what you are doing.

Comment: I know what I am doing, I just do not remember all the types @rioV8

Answer (score 0):

So you mean you want get the correct type of variables in Python.
You can refer to **Type Hint** feature.
Type hinting is a feature in Python that allows you to specify the data type of a variable or function argument. It was introduced in Python 3.5 and is specified in PEP 4841. Here’s an example:

```
def greet(name: str) -> str:
    return "Hello, " + name
```

The variable's type could be changed in Python, so that's not forced.
Back to your question, if you want to get the specify data type of variable which assigned by a function, you must specify the data type of the function return.